# Sudden error message that dataframe is not known

Tags: dataframe, undefined

I am working on a thesis for getting a certified data analyst. I am working with the following dataset https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/445/absenteeism+at+work -  I have done data refinement and saved the dataframe as df_renamed1. I have done almost all my work and I wanted to add some additional plots - suddenly I got the following error message. I haven´t changed or refined anything on the database - yesterday night I ran latest changes successfully and this morning the execution of the same code runst into this error.
Does anybody has an idea, what went wrong or what I can do?

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZdG1.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r0Iq.png)

I went through the code again - but as mentioned before I haven´t changed anything.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. From the image you shared, you seem to be using a Jupyter notebook. On a jupyter notebook, cell execution order matters (i.e. the order in which you run your code). 
What you shared does not allow to reproduce or even understand the origin of the problem.

You are probably trying to run a cell that uses a variable (`df_renamed_1`) before running the cell that defines the variable. Where is `df_renamed_1` defined in your code?